# Как через Бизнес-процессы в Битрикс24 создать событие в календаре?

Tags: php, битрикс, битрикс24

В коробочной версии Битрикс24 имеется календарь. В нём, в ячейке с днём/датой необходимо отображать даты рождения сотрудников и их ФИО. За неделю до др необходимо оповещать по почте ответственных руководителей.

Как это сделать через Бизнес-процессы?

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку для списка сотрудников нет возможности запускать бизнес-процесс, то вам понадобится универсальный список с полями "Сотрудник" и "День рождения". Для этого списка создаете бизнес-процесс в котором настраиваете запуск активити "Событие календаря" и активити "Почтовое сообщение".

Comment: Этот список в каком разделе создаётся?

Comment: "Сервисы"-"Списки"